# How can I do an eval correctly in Python?

Tags: python, eval, eof

I'm trying to evaluate a string in a Flask project, but I keep getting this error.

```
File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

This is the code I am using

```
def f(x):
   input = "math.log((math.sin(x)**2) + 1) - (1 / 2)"
   string = input.replace("x",str(x))
   result = eval(string)
   return result
```

Comment: What is `replace`?

Comment: If at all possible, don't. Find a better option. What that option is will depend on your underlying goal - if you just want to evaluate that particular mathematical expression, it's not clear why you're trying to use `eval` at all.

Comment: Why aren't you just doing `return math.log(math.sin(x)**2+1) - 0.5`?

Comment: because the input has to be a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because replace is a method of the string class, it must be called from the string itself.

```
def f(x):
   input = "math.log((math.sin(x)**2) + 1) - (1 / 2)"
   string = input.replace("x",str(x))
   result = eval(string)
   return result
```

But, you should avoid calling eval unless you absolutely have to; eval is evil. Eval (and its cousin exec) can open up your program to arbitrary code injections.

Can you explain your usecase a little more and I can see if I can suggest a better alternative?

Why wouldn’t this work:

```
def f(x):
    return math.log((math.sin(x)**2) + 1) - (1 / 2)
```

Comment: thank you, I would do it like you suggested but I'm trying to take the string input of a user in a flask app website, and the function has to change every time, I'm trying to take the user input as they would do in python , it's only meant to run locally for an assingment.

Comment: Gotcha. Just remember that for the future. Good luck, and if this helped consider clicking the check mark and upvoting the answer. In the future, when you are stuck on something like this I recommend using the tool pdb (python debugger) to step through your code and find the error. Just put the code `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` right before the code that’s giving you problems. There’s a bit of a learning curve, but it will save hundreds of hours in the future

Answer (score -1):

Try to change

```
result = eval(string)
return result
```

to

```
return eval(string)
```